# How is this function climbing up the prototype chain in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

This is an exercise from a course, which has one create a function to simulate how properties are retrieved from objects, so you get a better idea what is happening.

```
DOT = function dotFunc(obj, prop){
  // if this obj has this property just return it
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
      return obj[prop];

  // otherwise keep waking up the proto chain
  } else if (obj.__proto__){
      return DOT(obj.__proto__, prop);
  }
};
```

My problem is with the else if...
I take it to be saying "If this object has a `__proto__` property, return the DOT function again but this time using `obj.__proto__` as the first value. Is this essentially doing `obj.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__` recursively until it finds the property?

Comment: The answer is yes. ;))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, as @georg simply answered: *"The answer is yes"*.

If I had to develop on that, your recursive function will actually return two values: either the property's value or `undefined`.

Because implicitly, if the property is not in the proto chain, then the `if`/`else` will not return, and the function will return nothing which defaults to returning `undefined`.

HTH ☺